# How can I pass state to an action in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have some state in my component that I want to pass to an action
in React.js. How can I do this?

mycomponent.js

```
cityHandleUpdateInput() {
    this.setState({
        city: this.refs.city.refs.searchTextField.input.value
    })
    const { city } = this.state;
    this.props.fetchResCity(city)
}
```

myaction.js

```
export const fetchResCity = (city) => (dispatch, getState) =>  {
if (!getState().resCity.isFetching) {
    console.log(getState().city)
    console.log(city)
    const endpoint = 'rescity?city=${city}';
    dispatch({
        [CALL_API]: {
            types: [ RES_CITY_REQUEST, RES_CITY_SUCCESS, RES_CITY_FAILURE ],
            endpoint: endpoint
        }
    })
    }
}
```

It's not working. Is there something wrong in my code?
When I log that city variable in my action it's just `undefined`.

Comment: is It loggng in properly in cityHandleUpdateInput

Comment: I think setState will take time to update the state. Can you just pass `this.refs.city.refs.searchTextField.input.value` in fetchCity function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the `setState` callback i.e a correct way to handle state mutations since `setState` takes time to mutate the state and hence any use of state immediately after updating the state may result in the older value and not the updated value.

Make use of callback like

```
cityHandleUpdateInput() {
    this.setState({
        city: this.refs.city.refs.searchTextField.input.value
    }, () => {
        const { city } = this.state;
        this.props.fetchResCity(city)
    })  
}
```

Make sure that you are binding the `cityHandleUpdateInput` function in `constructor` or from where it is being called or otherwise it itself won't be able to access the `setState` with `this.setState`

Answer (score 1):

`setState` won't immediately update `this.state`. Here is the explanation from the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> `setState()` does not immediately mutate `this.state` but creates a pending state transition. Accessing `this.state` after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.
>
> There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to `setState` and calls may be batched for performance gains.

That means you'd need to store the value you are passing to `setState`, and pass that to your action creator as well. Something like this (I didn't run this code, make sure you test it) should work:

```
cityHandleUpdateInput() {
    const city = this.refs.city.refs.searchTextField.input.value;
    this.setState({ city });
    this.props.fetchResCity(city);
}
```