# How do I pass state into my action creator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I wanted to know how I can pass the state into an action so that it can use the state to make an API call. the state I want to pass is the input because it's the image URL that gets sent to Clarifai's servers to predict the celebrity. The handle search is responsible for updating state to the URL.

I've tried to use get state with no luck

**This is my action**

```
export const requestPrediction = () => {
  return function (dispatch, getState) {
    dispatch(fetchCelebrequest)
    let input = getState().input 
    app.models.predict(Clarifai.CELEBRITY_MODEL,
      input)
      .then(res => {
        const data = res.outputs[0]['data']['regions'][0]['data'].concepts[0]
        dispatch(fetchCelebSuccess(data))
      })
      .catch(err => {
        const error = err.message
        dispatch(fetchCelebFailed(error))
      })
  }
}
```

**This is my reducer.js**

```
import { 
    CHANGE_SEARCHFIELD,
    REQUEST_PREDICTION_PENDING,
    REQUEST_PREDICTION_SUCESS,
    REQUEST_PREDICTION_FAILED
} from './constants'


const initialState = {
    input: '',
    imageUrl: '',
    box: {},
    isSignedIn: false,
    isPending: false,
    celeb: {},
    error: '',
    celebConfidence: [],
    user: {
    id: '',
    name: '',
    email: '',
    entries: 0,
    joined: ''
    }
}

export const handleSearch = (state=initialState, action={}) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CHANGE_SEARCHFIELD:
            return { ...state, input: action.payload }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export const requestPrediction = (state=initialState, action={}) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case REQUEST_PREDICTION_PENDING:
            return {...state, isPending: true}
        case REQUEST_PREDICTION_SUCESS:
            return {...state, celebName: action.payload, isPending: false}
        case REQUEST_PREDICTION_FAILED:
            return {...state, error: action.payload, isPending: false}
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do it is via setState since the updates my be asynchronous.
You may check out this link. [How can I pass state to an action in React.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42335936/how-can-i-pass-state-to-an-action-in-react-js)

Comment: The state isn't coming from a component though, Is it supposed to?

Comment: Where you want to get state in order to pass it to the dispatch in your example? In most cases it is coming from the Component: for example a user clicks on the button.

Comment: Yeah so when the user clicks on the button it updates the input state in the redux store, I'm not sure how to access that state from my action

Comment: The usual flow is when the use clicks you update the state with setState, then you dispatch that to the store (for example from handleClick function). Once this value is dispatched you can access it from mapStatetoProps.

Comment: You would make `requestPrediction` be a function of `input` rather than using `getState` to select the input value.  Keep the state of the input local to the component, and the component will call `dispatch(requestPrediction(input))`.